# Bootstrap 4 navbar right aligned search option along with Signup

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a navbar with Serch option along with Login options. I want to make the Search option right-aligned just before the  Signup option. I need some help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand "><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Photo Galary</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control border border-right-0" placeholder="Search...">
                <span class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light border border-left-0" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<div class="container">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand "><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Photo Galary</a> 
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
           <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control border border-right-0" placeholder="Search...">
                 <span class="input-group-append">
                 <button class="btn btn-outline-light border border-left-0" type="button">
                 <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                 </button>
                 </span>
              </div>
           </form>
         <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login <i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div> </nav>
```

In `Bootstrap-4` `float-right` won't work because Bootstrap is now a `flexBox`. You can use `ml-auto`.

[image: Okay!! I edit it here is an output]

Comment: I have used ml-auto in my code. What I was looking for search Option before the Signup and not After Login.